# VS Code won't parse wsl path

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

1. Create a file via wsl.
   [image]
2. Try to open it with VS Code.
   [image]
3. VS Code won't open the file that is just created, but open a new one in E:\mnt\e.
   [image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) seems to be a Windows application (and does not understand *Ubuntu* paths in itself).

Use regular Windows path as follows:

```
code "e:\test.txt"
```

or even *almost* regular Windows path:

```
code "e:/test.txt"
```